# Parse non standard date format

Tags: bash, parsing, date

Say I have the following format outputted for my date:

```
date --utc +%d.%m.%Y,\ %H:%M\ UTC
# Outputs: 12.06.2014, 09:03 UTC
```

How can I display the outputted date above, in another `date` call, in another format? I tried:

```
date --utc --date="12.06.2014, 09:03 UTC" +%d.%m.%Y,\ %H:%M\ UTC
```

but with no success (it says `invalid date`).

I am primarily trying to do this in order to be able to tell from an outputted date how many hours have passed (or days, or whatever time measuring unit).

Comment: Just remove the comma and replace dots with slashes: `date --utc +%d/%m/%Y\ %H:%M\ UTC`.

Comment: You can specify a custom date format in `bsd date`, but can't in `gnu`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what the `man date` page says about format for the `--date` option:

```
The --date=STRING is a mostly free format human readable date string such as
"Sun, 29 Feb 2004 16:21:42 -0800" or "2004-02-29 16:21:42" or even "next
Thursday". A date string may contain items indicating calendar date, time of day,
time zone, day of week, relative time, relative date, and numbers. An empty
string indicates  the beginning of the day. The date string format is more
complex than is easily documented here but is fully described in the info
documentation.
```

Hence you can use, for example:

```
date --date "2014-06-12 09:03 UTC" --utc +%d.%m.%Y,\ %H:%M\ UTC
# Output: 12.06.2014, 09:03 UTC
```

to get what you desire.

You could get this second form easily from your first output with a `sed` line as follows:

```
sed 's/\([0-9]\{2\}\)\.\([0-9]\{2\}\)\.\([0-9]\{4\}\), \(.*\)/\3-\2-\1 \4/'
    <<< '12.06.2014, 09:03 UTC'
# Output: 2014-06-12 09:03 UTC
```

Note that it would probably be faster to output date at ISO 8601 format in the first time for reuse, e.g. with:

```
date --utc +%F\ %H:%M\ UTC
# Output: 2014-06-12 10:12 UTC
```

Comment: I don't have the same version of `date` as you do, probably. Therefore I cannot perform the above.

Comment: @AndreiHorak You mean, the first `date` command I wrote (taking `--date "2014-06-12 09:03 UTC"` as input)? I'm using `date (GNU coreutils) 8.20`. Don't know what's your version (`$ date --version`) and what the differences could be :/

Comment: I have `date (GNU coreutils) 8.13`, but it seems that for `--date` all I have is `display time described by STRING, not now`.

Comment: @AndreiHorak The paragraph I put was at the end of `man` page (section `DATE STRING`), not close to the `--date` option description, if it can help. Also did you try `$ info  date`?

Comment: My bad, I didn't notice that. Still, I cannot reformat an already formatted date: for `12.06.2014, 11:07`, `12.06.2014 11:07`, `12-06-2014 11:07` says `invalid date`.

Comment: @AndreiHorak Try `2014-06-12` instead of `12-06-2014`, as in my answer.

Comment: I need to use the format which I already have, `12.06.2014, 09:03 UTC`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55497/discussion-between-qeole-and-andrei-horak).

Comment: Fixed in chat. One can obtain the correct format for input with the `sed` command. We are still open to handier solutions without long `sed` line.

Answer (score 1):

I think you cannot specify **input** format, so you'll have to change it with another command like this:

```
date  --utc  --date="$(echo "12.06.2014, 09:03 UTC" | sed -r 's/(..).(..).(....), (..):(..) UTC/\3-\2-\1 \4:\5 UTC/')"
```

Also if you want to make arithmethic on this you could use `+%s`:

```
DATE1=$(date  "+%s"  --date="$(echo "12.06.2014, 09:03 UTC" | sed -r 's/(..).(..).(....), (..):(..) UTC/\3-\2-\1 \4:\5 UTC/')")
DATE2=$(date  "+%s"  --date="$(echo "17.06.2014, 08:30 UTC" | sed -r 's/(..).(..).(....), (..):(..) UTC/\3-\2-\1 \4:\5 UTC/')")
DIFF_IN_SECONDS=$(($DATE2-$DATE1))
DIFF_IN_RAW_DAYS=$(( ($DATE2-$DATE1)/86400 ))
DIFF_IN_DATES=$(( (($DATE2/86400) - ($DATE1/86400)) ))
```